# Importing Craft CMS Locally

Tags: install, import

I've inherited an existing website created using CraftCMS and hosted on Fortrabbit.

I'm fairly new to CraftCMS but anxious to get started on a couple of updates. The site currently exists on Fortrabbit. I have SSH and SFTP access and can see the files and have a fresh version of CraftCMS locally installed but unsure how to bring in the files. I'm aware it's built on the server so just not sure what parts I need to bring locally.

I have already grabbed and imported the DB to the MySQL content but just need this last step.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So having tried bringing it locally and getting a multitude of errors, I realized the live site was version 2 and I was installing version 3.

Following the upgrade guide solved it for me (among some minor plugin tweaks).

Comment: For future ref you can find the Craft version you need from the database in the craft_info table and download a specific version as per https://craftcms.com/guides/downloading-previous-craft-versions

Comment: That might be where i went to realise it - I've now got the site successfully migrated to the latest . Good to know about previous versions though, thank you :)